# How to track all signal in 'trap'?

Tags: shell, signals, trap

Can I test keyboard shortcuts and some `kill` commands with a script and know which signal is caught by `trap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this script, you can test all signal:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Know which signal is caught
# man 7 signal
trap "echo 'SIGHUP        1       Term    Hangup (disconnection) or control process termination.'" 1
trap "echo 'SIGINT        2       Term    Interrupt from keyboard.'" 2
trap "echo 'SIGQUIT       3       Core    Quit request from keyboard.'" 3
trap "echo 'SIGILL        4       Core    Illegal instruction.'" 4
trap "echo 'signal 5 not referenced'" 5
trap "echo 'SIGABRT       6       Core    Abort signal from abort(3).'" 6
trap "echo 'signal 7 not referenced'" 7
trap "echo 'SIGFPE        8       Core    Floating point arithmetic error.'" 8
trap "echo 'signal 10 not referenced'" 10
trap "echo 'SIGSEGV      11       Core    Invalid memory reference.'" 11
trap "echo 'signal 12 not referenced'" 12
trap "echo 'SIGPIPE      13       Term    Write on a pipe with no reader.'" 13
trap "echo 'SIGALRM      14       Term    Alarm clock signal (used by alarm(2)).'" 14
trap "echo 'SIGTERM      15       Term    Termination signal.'" 15
trap "echo 'SIGUSR1   30,10,16    Term    User-defined signal 1.'" 30 10 16
trap "echo 'SIGUSR2   31,12,17    Term    User-defined signal 2.'" 31 12 17
trap "echo 'SIGCHLD   20,17,18    Ign     Child stopped or terminated.'" 20 17 18
trap "echo 'SIGCONT   19,18,25    Cont    Continue if stopped.'" 19 18 25
trap "echo 'SIGTSTP   18,20,24    Stop    Stop signal generated from keyboard.'" 18 20 24
trap "echo 'SIGTTIN   21,21,26    Stop    Background process attempting to read from tty.'" 21 21 26
trap "echo 'SIGTTOU   22,22,27    Stop    Background process attempting to write to tty.'" 22 22 27
trap "echo 'SIGWINCH  28,28,20    Ign     Window resize signal (4.3 BSD, Sun).'" 28 20
read _
```

The signals `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored. (`9`, `19`).

See [man 7 signal](https://man.archlinux.org/man/signal.7.en)

And http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap

---

To avoid copy/paste:

```
wget -O signal-finder.sh https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sputnick-dev/7260ac0aa46f067f469ee8184b69acb3/raw/4286bcda6d3353aad7584ab320048af4d8bfa197/gistfile1.txt
chmod +x signal-finder.sh
./signal-finder.sh
```